# How to get latitude and longitude values in android app without prompting user for permission?

Tags: java, android, location

I am trying develop an android app using JAVA to obtain the user's current latitude and longitude values after checking if the GPS is enabled. What is a suitable way to achieve this, while not prompting the user for any permissions?
I tried to analyze many codes for similar question however, some doesn't work and others were very comprehensive as to what was asked. Can anyone please provide a code to extract latitude and longitude values after checking if GPS is enabled?

Comment: It would be a terrible breach of the entire Android security system if that was at all possible - users must grant your app permission before they have access to location data of any kind. That kind of vulnerability should be reported via the [Android Security Rewards program](https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/android-rewards/).

Comment: You can not get a location of the user without asking for permission. Location is a sensitive data in which you have to have the permission in order to get it.